# Setting height of elements with js breaking on higher resolution computers

Tags: jquery, loops, screen-resolution

I'm loading several elements to a page dynamically, all with the same markup structure. Basically these are products that can all be clicked through for further information.

I'm using jQuery to get the height of the tallest instance and applying that height (+25px padding) to all instances in order to keep a consistent grid appearance.

This works fine for smaller screens, like my 13 inch computer, but when I look at it on a large desktop, the instances are loading too short and the content is coming out of the bottom.

Can anyone point me towards a fix here? Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated!

Here's my markup for each instance:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="product-archive-item">
        <div class="product-archive-image"></div>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <span class="price"><?php $price(); ?></span>     
    </div> <!-- .product-archive-item -->
</a>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
var bigbrother = -1;

$('.product-archive-item').each(function() {
         bigbrother = bigbrother > $('.product-archive-item').height() ? bigbrother : $('.product-archive-item').height() +25+'px';
});

$('.product-archive-item').each(function() {
    $('.product-archive-item').height(bigbrother);
});
```

I've also added a picture of the discrepancy between the two screens, in case that might help.

[image: Smaller Screen]
[image: Larger Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main things :

1. You absolutely don't need JS for this. CSS handles it perfectly with Flexbox.
2. JS is MUCH slower than CSS, and on top of that, your code is super heavy and not optimized. You're not caching any jQuery object, making constant DOM access, you iterate twice, and the last `.each` is totally useless; `$('.product-archive-item').height(bigbrother)` is enough and will apply to all items.

Just use CSS (Thanks @PranbirSarkar for the markup :) :

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 600px;
}
.items a {
  border: #f00 dashed 2px;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
 <a href="#">
  <div class="product-archive-item">
   <div class="product-archive-image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></div>
   <h3>Product 1 title</h3>
   <span class="price">$100</span>
  </div>
  <!-- .product-archive-item -->
 </a>
 <a href="#">
  <div class="product-archive-item">
   <div class="product-archive-image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></div>
   <h3>Product 2 title big title will take more space will take more space</h3>
   <span class="price">$100</span>
  </div>
  <!-- .product-archive-item -->
 </a>
 <a href="#">
  <div class="product-archive-item">
   <div class="product-archive-image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></div>
   <h3>Product 3</h3>
   <span class="price">$100</span>
  </div>
  <!-- .product-archive-item -->
 </a>
 <a href="#">
  <div class="product-archive-item">
   <div class="product-archive-image"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></div>
   <h3>Product 4</h3>
   <span class="price">$100</span>
  </div>
  <!-- .product-archive-item -->
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You did a small mistakes.
You called `.each` but after that at the time when you calculating the highest value, you are taking the value of first div only..

Explaining the mistakes :

1) You comparing with `$('.product-archive-item').height()` so always it is taking the height of the first div that have the class `product-archive-item` . You have to use `$(this).height()` to calculate dynamically.

2) you used  `+25+'px'` after each loop.. That mean you are converting the datatype of the variable named `bigbrother` to string.. This is causing also.. If you want to add 25 extra, then you add 25px after the loop get completed.

That mean your JQuery part will be :

```
 var bigbrother = -1;

$('.product-archive-item').each(function() {
         bigbrother = bigbrother > $(this).height() ? bigbrother : 
         $(this).height();
   });
       bigbrother = bigbrother+25;

       $('.product-archive-item').height(bigbrother);
```

Here is the JsFiddle link for working example
https://jsfiddle.net/m8wbp6s3/4/

Comment: I can't upvote that, because even though it works, it's still uselessly and heavily  using JS (although you optimized it a bit), where two simple lines of CSS do the trick. Not downvoting either, though :)

Comment: Yes. This can be done with CSS and If we do with that it will be more better. I agree with that. 

But In this case the developer want to set the dynamic height using JavaScript. That's why I provide the solution in JS not CSS. 

Happy Coding .. :)

Comment: The developer _wants_ to use JS... for what reason, other that he doesn't know that it's clumsy and could easily be handled by CSS? He doesn't  _want_ to use JS. He uses what he knows, within the limits of his knowledge. We all do.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This was very helpful to read about. Jeremy, you were correct in assuming I'd like to do it the best way possible and was instead just doing it in a way that made sense to me.